# correcting values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary using this code:

```
import collections

exons = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('test_coding.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        chrom, start, end, isoform = line.split()
        exons[isoform].append((int(start), int(end)))
```

This code produces a dictionary that looks as so:

```
{'NM_100': [(75, 90), (100, 120)], 'NM_200': [(25, 50), (55, 75), (100, 125), (155, 200)]})
```

from this file:

```
chr1    75  90  NM_100
chr1    100 120 NM_100
chr2    25  50  NM_200
chr2    55  75  NM_200
chr2    100 125 NM_200
chr2    155 200 NM_200
```

What I want to do is subtract the first value in the list (in the first case, 75 and 25 for the second case) from every other value in that particular list for a desired output of:

```
{'NM_100': [(0, 15), (25, 45)], 'NM_200': [(0, 25), (30, 50), (75, 100), (130, 175)]})
```

I was thinking that I needed to create my dictionary in an alternative way. Kind of like below, but I can't get this function to work correctly.

```
def read_exons(line):
    parts = iter(line.split()) #I think the problem is here
    chrom = next(parts)
    start = next(parts)
    end = next(parts)
    base = start[0]    #and here
    return name, [(s-base, e-base) for s, e in zip(start, end)]

with open('testing_coding.txt') as f:
    exons = dict(read_exons(line) for line in f
        if not line.strip().startswith('#'))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this transformation , when reading the file you can create another dictionary , that contains the key as `isoform` and the value as the first value in the list, and then keep removing from it.

The issue with trying to do this without a separate dictionary or list is that if for the first line you do the subtraction, then for all other values that are read in, you would end up with subtracting `0` , which is the new value of the first element. Or you would have to first create the dict, and then re-iterate through it to do the subtraction.

Example -

```
import collections

exons = collections.defaultdict(list)
firstvalues = {}
with open('test_coding.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        chrom, start, end, isoform = line.split()
        if isoform not in firstvalues:
            firstvalues[isoform] = int(start)
        exons[isoform].append((int(start) - firstvalues[isoform], int(end) - firstvalues[isoform]))
```

Comment: I've tried to use this example, but I keep getting an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` for the last line. Do I need to make the `start` and `firstvalues[isoform]` integers independently?

Comment: Yes, you need to make them integers. Let me update that in answer.

Answer (score 2):

My Approach is to save the element you want to subtract on each iteration and then apply that using the `map` function, very basic and save the result on the same dictionary:

```
exons = {'NM_100': [(75, 90), (100, 120)], 'NM_200': [(25, 50), (55, 75), (100, 125), (155, 200)]}

for k,v in exons.items():
    x = d1[k][0][0] #Saving the first element of first tuple of each list
    for i,t in enumerate(v):
        exons[k][i] = tuple(map(lambda s: s-x, t)) #just to conserve the original format of your exons dictionany
```

Output:

```
>>> exons
{'NM_100': [(0, 15), (25, 45)], 'NM_200': [(0, 25), (30, 50), (75, 100), (130, 175)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in exons.items():
    s = value[0][0]
    exons[key] = [(x[0] - s, x[1]) for x in value]
```

Comment: @interstellar Sorry, I edited my answer, I forgot to use `.items()`.